# Make values in tensor fit in given range

Tags: performance, machine-learning, lua, torch

I have a 3d tensor and would like to ensure that all values fall within a given range (0-1 in this case). In order to do this I have already written the following code:

```
    function capTo1or0 (Tensor3d)

       tensor_width=Tensor3d:size()[2]
       tensor_height=Tensor3d:size()[3]
       tensor_depth=Tensor3d:size()[1]
       for i=1,tensor_width,1 do
           for j=1,tensor_height,1 do
               for k=1,tensor_depth,1 do 
                   if(Tensor3d[k][i][j])>1 then

                       Tensor3d[k][i][j]=1

                   end  
                   if(Tensor3d[k][i][j]<0.0) then
                        Tensor3d[k][i][j]=0.0           
                   end
               end
           end
        end
       return Tensor3d
    end
```

and it works, there is just one problem: performance is terrible, I know that there has to be some better way of doing this then looping over the entire array given that most tensor operations that do not involve manually looping over an array are much faster. Anybody know how to make this faster?

```
An example in this is say that I have a `2-3-3` array with the values

    [1,  2,  0.5][0.5,0.2,-0.2]
     [0.1,0.2,0.3][1,  1,   1  ]
    [-2, -1, 2  ][0.2,-5,-1   ]

then I expect an outcome of 
    [1,  1,  0.5][0.5,0.2,0]
    [0.1,0.2,0.3][1,  1,   1  ]
    [0, 0, 1  ]  [0.2,0,-1   ]
```

replacing every value under the lower bound of 0 with 0 and every value over the upper bound of 1 with 1.

Anybody know how to do this fast?

Comment: Sorry for the less then ideal formating around the array/tensors, it kept complaining about unformatted code and I think the keywords in and then were confusing it. If you have any more questions please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Torch, but it's documentation says:
http://torch7.readthedocs.io/en/rtd/maths/#torch.clamp

> [res] torch.clamp([res,] tensor1, min_value, max_value)
>
> Clamp all elements in the tensor into the range [min_value,
>   max_value]. ie:
>
> ```
> y_i = x_i, if x_i >= min_value or x_i <= max_value
>     = min_value, if x_i < min_value
>     = max_value, if x_i > max_value
> ```
>
> `z=torch.clamp(x,0,1)` will return a new tensor with the result of x
>   bounded between 0 and  1.
>
> `torch.clamp(z,x,0,1)` will put the result in z.
>
> `x:clamp(0,1)` will perform the clamp operation in place (putting the
>   result in x).
>
> `z:clamp(x,0,1)` will put the result in z.

I guess that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah thank you, clamped is the word I was looking for!